# Reading a special txt file in java

Tags: java, arrays

What I want to do is read a text file that has humans and animals. It will compile but has an error when I try to run it. I think I need a for loop to read the stringtokenizer to decipher between the human and animal in the txt file so far this is my driver class.

txt file:

```
Morely,Robert,123 Anywhere Street,15396,4,234.56,2
Bubba,Bulldog,58,4-15-2010,6-14-2011
Lucy,Bulldog,49,4-15-2010,6-14-2011
Wilder,John,457 Somewhere Road,78214,3,124.53,1
Ralph,Cat,12,01-16-2011,04-21-2012
Miller,John,639 Green Glenn Drive,96258,5,0.00,3
Major,Lab,105,07-10-2012,06-13-2013
King,Collie,58,06-14-2012,10-05-2012 
Pippy,cat,10,04-25-2015,04-25-2015
Jones,Sam,34 Franklin Apt B,47196,1,32.09,1
Gunther,Swiss Mountain Dog,125,10-10-2013,10-10-2013
Smith,Jack,935 Garrison Blvd,67125,4,364.00,4
Perry,Parrot,5,NA,3-13-2014
Jake,German Shepherd,86,11-14-2013,11-14-2013 
Sweetie,tabby cat,15,12-15-2013,2-15-2015
Pete,boa,8,NA,3-15-2015
```

Source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * This is my driver class that reads from a txt file to put into an array and uses the class refrences so it can use the menu and spit out  
 * 
 * @author ******
 * @version 11/25/2015
 */
public class Driver
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Driver, what it does is read in the txt file gets the two class refrences and loops through to read through the whole file looking for string tokens to go to the next line
     * and closes the file at the end also uses for loop to count number of string tokens to decipher between human and pets.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Pet p;
        Human h;
        Scanner input;
        char menu;
        input = new Scanner(new File("clientdata.txt"));

        int nBalance;
        int id;

        /**
         * this while statement goes through each line looking for the string tokenizer ",". I want to count each "," to decipher between Human and Animal
         */
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.nextLine(), ",");
            h = new Human();
            h.setLastName(st.nextToken());
            h.setFirstName(st.nextToken());
            h.setAddress(st.nextToken());
            h.setCiD(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            h.setVisits(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            h.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
            p = new Pet(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
        }
        /**
         * this is my seond while statement that loops the case switch statements and asks the user for client ID
         */
        menu = 'Y';
        while(menu == 'y' || menu == 'Y') {
            System.out.print("\nChose one:\n A- client names and outstanding balance \n B- client's pets, name, type and date of last visit\n C-change the client's outstanding balance: ");
            menu = input.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.print("Enter client ID: ");
            id = input.nextInt();
            h = new Human();
            if(id == h.getCiD())//if the id entered up top is equal to one of the id's in the txt file then it continues to the menu
            {
                p = new Pet();
             switch(menu)
       {    case 'A':
            System.out.println("client name: " + h.getFirstName() + "outstanding balance: " + h.getBalance());
             break;
             case 'B':
             System.out.println("pet's name: " + p.getName() + "type of pet: " + p.getTanimal() + "date of last visit: " + p.getLastVisit());
             break;
             case 'C':
             System.out.println("what do you want to change the clients balances to?");


        input.close();
       }
    }
    else// if not then it goes to this If statement saying that the Client does not exist
    { 
        System.out.println("Client does not exist.");
    }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Got an example of the file format?  You might have better luck using `String#split` rather then a `StrongTokenizer`

Comment: Yes sir should I just copy and past a few?

Comment: Yes please, add them to the question

Comment: okay I added the txt file sir

Comment: Are you restricted in what you can use?  A `List` would be really, really helpful here. Have a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: Yes, I am but I have a question. I see that humans and dogs in the txt file have different amounts of comma's since my stringtokenizer is a comma could I put them into an array with that?

Comment: You could use an array to store a list of `Human` and `Pet`s, but I imagine that each pet is associated with a human

Comment: Yes sir, so that wouldn't work :/ so I guess a list is the only way I could go?

Comment: An array can work, but you would need to know upfront the number of elements you would be adding to it, a `List` is more dynamic, which, personally, makes it a better choice.  The next question is, how do you distinguish between a human and a pet?

Comment: Hey. your text file is having different types of data. At first line and second line data is different.

Comment: Yes...the only thing I could think of is using tokenizer.counttokens() to count how many tokens there are and then putting it into the list of human...and animals but I don't know

Comment: Yes sir, the second line is an animal which belongs to the first line human

Comment: How you are recognizing that 2nd and third line is animal and 4th is again human???

Comment: first line is: Last name, first name, address, client ID, number of visits, balance, number of pets

Comment: second line is: Pet name, animal type, weight, rabies date, last visit date

Comment: But the problem is you are not trying to recognize if the current line is human or animal. How you think your program will work correctly. First think of how to get if the line is about animal or human.

Comment: Is it possible to change a file and put an indicator for human h and pet p

Comment: You have to decide how you will recognize if line is human or animal. You can use number of tokens, or number format

Comment: So, would I a pet array in the human class? or ask the user how many pets the human has?

Comment: just try to parse your file and use number of tokens to recognize type

Comment: afzalex, sir, if I use tokens how would I go about using them because I used "," and humans have 5 comma's while animals have 3 comma's

Comment: sorry human's have 6 comma's and animals have 3

Comment: @Dust by counting comma?

Comment: Yes sir by counting comma

Comment: @Dust I told you to split counting comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues you need to overcome...

- For each line, you need to determine the type of data the line represents
- You need some way to keep track of the data you've loaded (of the clients and their pets)
- You need some way to associate each pet with it's owner

The first could be done in a number of ways, assuming we can change the data.  You could make the first token meaningful (`human`, `pet`); you could use JSON or XML instead.  But lets assume for the moment, you can't change the format.

The key difference between the two types of data is the number of tokens they contain, 7 for people, 5 for pets.

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String text = input.nextLine();
    String[] parts = text.split(",");
    if (parts.length == 7) {
        // Parse owner
    } else if (parts.length == 5) {
        // Parse pet
    } // else invalid data
```

For the second problem you could use arrays, but you would need to know in advance the number of elements you will need, the number of people and for each person, the number of pets

Oddly enough, I just noticed that the last element is an `int` and seems to represent the number of pets!!

```
Morely,Robert,123 Anywhere Street,15396,4,234.56,2
                                     ------------^
```

But that doesn't help us for the owners.

For the owners, you could use a `List` of some kind and when ever you create a new `Human`, you would simply add them to the `List`, for example...

```
List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<>(25);
//...
    if (parts.length == 7) {
        // Parse the properties
        human = new Human(...);
        humans.add(human);
    } else if (parts.length == 5) {
```

Thirdly, for the pets, each `Pet` should associated directly with the owner, for example:

```
Human human = null;
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String text = input.nextLine();
    String[] parts = text.split(",");
    if (parts.length == 7) {
        //...
    } else if (parts.length == 5) {
        if (human != null) {
            // Parse pet properties
            Pet pet = new Pet(name, type, age, date1, date2);
            human.add(pet);
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException("Found pet without human");
        }
    }
```

Okay, so all this does, is each time we create a `Human`, we keep a reference to the "current" or "last" owner created.  For each "pet" line we parse, we add it to the owner.

Now, the `Human` class could use either a array or `List` to manage the pets, either will work, as we know the expected number of pets.  You would then provide getters in the `Human` class to get a reference to the pets.

Because out-of-context code can be hard to read, this is an example of what you might be able to do...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<>(25);
Human human = null;
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String text = input.nextLine();
    String[] parts = text.split(",");
    if (parts.length == 7) {
        String firstName = parts[0];
        String lastName = parts[1];
        String address = parts[2];
        int cid = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        int vists = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
        double balance = Double.parseDouble(parts[5]);
        int other = Integer.parseInt(parts[6]);
        human = new Human(firstName, lastName, address, cid, vists, balance, other);
        humans.add(human);
    } else if (parts.length == 5) {
        if (human != null) {
            String name = parts[0];
            String type = parts[1];
            int age = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            String date1 = parts[3];
            String date2 = parts[4];
            Pet pet = new Pet(name, type, age, date1, date2);
            human.add(pet);
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException("Found pet without human");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `split()` function instead of using `StringTokenizer`?

Say, You can change your first `while` loop like below:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
//  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.nextLine(), ",");
    String[] tokens = input.nextLine().split(",");
    if (tokens.length == 7) {
        h = new Human();
        h.setLastName(tokens[0]);
        h.setFirstName(tokens[1]);
        h.setAddress(tokens[2]);
        h.setCiD(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]));
        h.setVisits(Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
        h.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(tokens[5]));
    } else {
        p = new Pet(tokens[0], tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]), tokens[3], tokens[4]);
    }
}
```

And for keeping track of which pet belongs to which human, you can append an arrayList of type `Pet` in `Human` class like below:

```
ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
```

And say you have another `ArrayList` of type `Human` named `humans` in the main function. So, you could append in `if` block like:

```
humans.add(h);
```

and in the `else` section, you could append in `else` block:

```
humans.get(humans.size()-1).pets.add(p);
```

Comment: There's 7 tokens per `Human` :P - Then how do you 1- Keep track of all the humans you've created and 2- associate their pets with them?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh! Typo. I think he could handle it by appending an arrayList in `Human` class. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -
Populate a map and then using that you can assign values according to your requirement.

```
public void differentiate(){
    try {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//your filepath")));
            Map<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            List<String> petList=new ArrayList<String>();
            String s=scan.nextLine();
            String str[]=s.split(",");
            String name=str[1]+" "+str[0];
            int petCount=Integer.parseInt(str[str.length-1]);
                for(int i=1;i<=petCount;i++){
                 String petString=scan.nextLine();
                 petList.add(petString);
                }
                map.put(name, petList);
            }
            Set<String> set=map.keySet();
            for(String str:set){
                System.out.println(str+" has "+map.get(str)+" pets");
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```